# How to change color of text box in razor view ,onFocus and onBlur using jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

How can I change background color of textBox(text box is in razor view) onFocus or onBlur. I didn't understand which selector to use.

my razor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>student</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstname)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lastname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lastname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastname)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fathername)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fathername)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fathername)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

razor after rendering

```
<div class="editor-label">
            <label for="firstname">firstname</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" value="test1" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="firstname" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="lastname">lastname</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" value="test1" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="lastname" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
```

Now what tag I should use in script to raise event onFocus and onBlur
I tried using 
"textbox","text-box single-line"  using these and some other as selectors but they are working, con some one help me which selector i should use

Comment: Do you really need javascript to do this? Why not just with css: `.text-box input:focus { background-color: white; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the element and ["attribute equals"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector, such that:

```
$("input[type='text']").blur(function(e) {
  $(this).css("background", someColour);
});
```

will apply to all textboxes.